# WinDbg -- debugging mixed x64 managed/unmanaged code

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, unmanaged, windbg, managed-code

I'm using WinDbg (Native x64 -- NOT Itanium) to debug an x64 (unmanaged) application that loads both managed an unmanaged DLLs.

I'm trying to set a breakpoint in one of the unmanaged DLLs. When the breakpoint is hit and I step through, the instructions displayed are totally different from what they should be. I verified with two different disassemblers that WinDbg is not displaying the correct disassembly as I step through.

When attaching to the application, I get a line like this:

```
ModLoad: 00000000`XXXXXXXX 00000000`YYYYYYYY  C:\MyDLL.DLL
```

I adjusted the addresses in the two disassemblers to reflect the base address XXXXXXXX.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I found this (which never was completely answered):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398826/vs2008-on-win7-64-bit-debugging-a-windows-service

Maybe this helps?

Comment: does the disassembly make sense generally? i'd give the general preference to windbg since it is decoding using a valid ip in a live process which has benefits as opposed to solely relying on static analysis (however good a disassembler might be). can you reveal a bit of assembly code to compare?

Comment: It's "call someFunc" vs "mov ebx,esp". Even stepping at other points it doesn't match. It seems inconsistent in which breakpoints are hit; I set breakpoints that should be hit but aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Does uf modname!FuncName return the correct results? You can sometimes trick WinDbg if you unassemble / breakpoint at weird places. Remember, that x86/x64 is a variable-width instruction set, so if you start reading halfway through an instruction, the disassembler gets confused.

Comment: Do you think that the .NET interpreter could be changing things?

Comment: If I do "u <address>", it doesn't match. I'm not debugging with symbols. I also tried moving the address a little, doesn't help to get the right disassembly.

Comment: If you're not using symbols, WinDbg is going to give you trash information. Find the symbols for the DLL you need

Comment: I don't believe that. I've used WinDbg and it's given me a good disassembly (that matched the static disassembly perfectly). I've only started to have a problem when I moved from all-native x86 to mixed-mode x64.

Comment: Hmmm, let me rephrase - WinDbg will be untrustworthy when you don't have symbols, but not always incorrect. Anyways, what happens if you compare the raw bytes vs. what WinDbg reports via db @rip?

Comment: Raw bytes say that the static disassembly is correct and WinDbg is wrong, so that's why I'm worried about things changing during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere i've noticed info that this may be related to improper entry point in your DLL. But I have no clue what to do with this information (i'm beginner).